# Scanning ports with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Is it possible to scan several ports at once with `AsyncTask`? I am totally new to `AsyncTask`, so I have no clue what I am doing. Even after reading all tutorials on the internet about `AsyncTask` (eg Vogella etc.) I still can't understand how to make this happen.

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText et;
    Button b;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }

    public void start(View view){
        GetPorts task = new GetPorts();
        task.execute(20,53,80,114,140);
    }

    private class GetPorts extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Vector<Integer>> {

        Vector<Integer> openPorts = new Vector<Integer>();

        @Override
        protected Vector<Integer> doInBackground(Integer... ports) {


            for(Integer port: ports){

                try {
                    Socket socket = new Socket();
                    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", port), 500);
                    socket.close();
                    openPorts.add(port);
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
            }
            return openPorts;
        }
    }
}
```

the ports 20,53,80 etc are the example porst I'd like to check (there could be up to 65535 ports). I thought checking ports and adding them to `Vector` and then returning this `Vector` would be a good idea, but I have no idea how to do that. I wonder if my `Vector` "openPorts" is going to reset with every new port to scan, and will this `AsyncTask` be able to scan multiple ports at the same time?

I have created the working solution with Java SE and I'm gonna paste it here to clarify what I am after of.

Java SE code:

```
public class Scanner {

    private final String ip;
    private final int sPort, ePort, timeout, poolSize;
    private Vector<Integer> openPorts = new Vector<Integer>();
    private final ExecutorService es;
    private Collection<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedList<Future<?>>();


    public Scanner(String ip, int sPort, int ePort, int timeout, int poolSize) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.sPort = sPort;
        this.ePort = ePort;
        this.timeout = timeout;
        this.poolSize = poolSize;
        es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(this.poolSize);

    }

    public Vector<Integer> getPorts() {
        Collections.sort(openPorts);
        return openPorts;
    }

    public void runScanner() {

        for (int startPort = sPort; startPort <= ePort; startPort++) {
            futures.add(es.submit(new Check(ip, startPort, timeout)));
        }

        es.shutdown();

    }

    public void stopScanner(){
        for (Future<?> future : futures) {
            future.cancel(true);
        }
    }

    private class Check implements Runnable {

        private String ip;
        private int port, timeout;

        private Check(String ip, int port, int timeout) {
            this.ip = ip;
            this.port = port;
            this.timeout = timeout;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), timeout);
                socket.close();
                openPorts.add(port);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
    }                                      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your vector will be reset only when you instanciate a new `GetPorts` class (as usual).
Your code looks just fine. If your problem is to retrieve the result of the `AsyncTask`, you have two main ways to achieve it.

You can just call `Vector<Integer> v = new GetPorts().execute(20,53,80,114,140).get();` but it's not often a proper way.

Or you can implements callback in the `AsyncTask` post execute callback.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Vector<Integer> result) {
}
```

Your `AsyncTask` should be like this:

```
 private class GetPorts extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Vector<Integer>> {

    public interface MyCallbackInterface {
    public void myCallback(Vector<Integer> ports);
    }

    MyCallbackInterface listener;
    Vector<Integer> openPorts = new Vector<Integer>();

    public GetPorts(MyCallbackInterface listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Vector<Integer> doInBackground(Integer... ports) {


        for(Integer port: ports){

            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", port), 500);
                socket.close();
                openPorts.add(port);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
        return openPorts;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Vector<Integer> result) {
         listener.myCallback(result);
    }
}
```

Then in the task caller which implements `MyCallbackInterface`, you can do:

`new GetPorts(this).execute(20,53,80,114,140);`

And doing what you want in :

```
 @Override
 public void myCallback(Vector<Integer> ports) {
 }
```

Comment: but how do I get that (Vector<Integer> result) from main activity?

Comment: Sorry my post was sent before I finished. If you call the task from your activity and you just want actualize the UI you can do this in the `AsyncTask` callback. Else you can define an interface and register your activity as a listener. I can edit my post with a sample if you want.

Comment: Updated, let me know if it's what you are looking for.

Comment: Do I need to have my asynctask in class that extends MyCallbackInterface?

Comment: No. As you don't have to specify the interface in the asynctask. It just works as all other class. `AsyncTask` just help to update the UI after background processing but you can use them as simple thread.

Comment: but calling new GetPorts(this).execute(20,53,80,114,140); gives me error

Comment: this error: The constructor MainActivity.GetPorts(MyCallbackInterface) refers to the missing type MyCallbackInterface

Comment: Are you sure you have correctly defined `MyCallbackInterface` and have the good imports? It seems just a basic JAVA error. Else edit your post with the code you are testing.

Comment: it says: The member interface MyCallbackInterface can only be defined inside a top-level class or interface

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15511/discussion-between-rohit-malish-and-fabif)